# Unity license error on startup

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm having an issue at launching unity.

I just install Unity, log-in via google and had that error.

Now, the bug appears with not even login in.

I tried to reinstall, remove registry and it stills happen with not even login in anymore.

There's the link where you can see the bucle it keeps doing.

https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/AdmiredIcyAmericanwirehair
[image]

As you can see it keeps refreshing the license screen like it's trying to load something.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Unity has a very responsive bug report system, you might want to go to the website and report it there

Comment: Thank you, didn't know. I submit the bug there, here and on reddit. no answers yet. Hope someone know something about the issue, i was so hyped to start learning Unity.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 as your OS? If the answer is yes, did you recently have a large update?  If yes to both of these, I will have something you can try.

Comment: Yes! I'm using W10 and i had a few updates recently. What can i try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a way to fix this problem.

First of all you have to know that the issue was with the license, it didn't activate properly, so it just keeps trying to activate again and again, and that's where the bucle was.

To solve this, i follow some steps made by myself, that came from a lot of research and combining some tutorials for others problems.

---

The first problem was I log-in only once, the first time I installed. After that I was unable to login again even with reinstall and remove registry. So I couldn't stop the bucle.

To fix that you need to uninstall Unity, remove registry (Ccleaner for example) and remove some **hidden** directories manually:

```
C:\ProgramData\Unity

C:\ProgramFiles\Unity or C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Unity

C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Unity

C:\Users\(username)\AppData\LocalLow\Unity

C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Unity
```

After removing all those files, you can have a clean install of unity, if you don't remove those, it will keeps login in on the same acc and keeping the bucle on.

So, after doing that the bucle will stop and it will let you login again. **First problem solved**

---

Now if you log-in the bucle will happen again, so we need to activate the license without login in. And we're doing it with the offline activation.

1. Unplug your ethernet, disconect from wifi, whatever, just make sure you don't have connection.
2. Open Unity and check that says "No connection: Quit or Manual Activation".
3. Click "Manual Activation" and **download** the License Request.
4. Close Unity and connect your internet.
5. Go to the official Unity Manual Activation Page and upload your Request File.
6. Download the aproved license, it will request you an Unity account.
7. Unplug again the internet and open Unity on offline mode.
8. Click "Manual Activation" and **upload** the Aproved License.
9. Make sure you have now access to Unity on offline mode and close it.

**Second problem solved**: License activated.

Now you only need to connect again your internet, then open Unity and you will see an activated license without login-in, so you can now log-in with the account you used on step 6.

And now the problem is solved. You have the activated license and you're logged-in.

It tooks me like "2 days" to make this solution for this poblem, hope i can help someone with this tuto and save ur time.

Comment: don't work for me. I spend 2 hours now just to get the ide started.Frustrating... :(

Answer (score 3):

1- exit from unity

2- go to C:\ProgramData\Unity

3- remove Unity_lic.ulf

4- open unity

5- reactivate the license

and it work.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the unity_lic.ulf found in program data and open unity and it will works!

Comment: yeah see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I did was extremely simple. I just selected the re-activate button I found on the right and then I followed the instructions or better, I answered the questions. I selected Unity Personal and since I don't work, I use it as a hobby I selected "I don't use Unity in a professional way". Then, I just pressed the button on the screen and then Unity worked perfectly fine.